# In MTG I have a Fear card

Tags: magic-the-gathering

How can I find out what type of expansion my fear card is from since it's either Summer Edge or Alpha. Anyway's for me to find out from what expansion it is from?[image]

Comment: You can look at the art (and border) on [gatherer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=3845) to narrow it down

Comment: If you add a photo of the card then the clever folk here will be able to help you a lot better :-)

Comment: I overlayed it with another normal card and yup. Its a limited edition alpha :D

Comment: The wording makes me think Alpha or Beta, since the third edition has the updated text on it